# Like a Facebook page and Display Pages Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-wall

All,
I'm trying to create a welcome landing spot for my facebook page. If a user hasn't liked my page yet I'd like to display an image to them asking them to like my page. After the user has liked my page I'd like to have them redirected to my pages wall and since they already liked my page whenever they come back to visit my page I'd like the default landing spot to be my wall instead of my welcome page. Does anyone have any good tutorials or suggestions on how to do something like this?

I tried to install the following app http://www.facebook.com/welcometabapp which works fine for making the page my default but then I can't make it so that when the user comes back it goes to the wall.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this for my welcome page:

```
<?php
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/Website?sk=wall";
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

    if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
        echo '<img src="../images/facebook_welcome_page_new.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">';
    } else {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in PHP -

http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php

then where the content is output for when a user has liked the page; instead output a JS redirect to the wall, so using something like this...

```
echo "<script> top.location.href='http://www.facebook.com/yourpage?sk=wall';</script>";
```

instead of this line

```
echo "This content is for Fans only!";
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for a facebook fan page is to show the wall as the default tab for fans who have liked your page.